# Try to make changeable background like twitter

Tags: php, html, forms, jquery, twitter

Ok This might be a unique question to some of you here. I'm making a site by which user can change there account background.. so i have reached till this far..now i need help here.

**Javascript code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#photoimg').live('change', function()            { 
                       $("#preview").html('');
                $("#preview").html("<body background="http://mysite.com/image/loading.jpg"></body>");
            $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                        target: '#preview'
        }).submit();

            });
        }); 
</script>
```

**In HTML i've placed this code**

This is the place where echo is placed
`<div id="preview"></div>`

1. I tried here by div tag

   `<div id="preview">
   <body background="http://mysite.com/image/please_add_backqround.jpg"></body>
   </div>`
2. I tried then by style in background

   `<div id="preview">
   <body style="background-image: url(http://mysite.com/image/please_add_backqround.jpg);">
   </div>
   </body>`
3. I tried then by style in div which covers almost whole page.

   `<html><body>
   <div id="preview">
   <div id="covering_whole_page" style="background-image:url ( http://mysite.com/image/please_add_backqround.jpg);"></div></div></html>`

None of them are working. :(

**Html Form**

`<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
<input type="file" title="upload your fav. background" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" onchange="pressedx()"></form>`

**ajaximage.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$session_id='1'; //$session id
$path = "uploads/";

    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
        {
            $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
            $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

            if(strlen($name))
                {
                    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                    {
                    if($size<(1024*1024))
                        {
                            $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                                {
                                //sqlquery space
                        echo "<body background='uploads/".$actual_image_name."' ></body>";
                        }
                            else
                                echo "failed";
                        }
                        else
                        echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
                        }
                        else
                        echo "Invalid file format..";   
                }

            else
                echo "Please select image..!";

            exit;
        }
?>
```

Please help me in making it right also i want to add the file uploaded to DATABASE so when user click SAVE that particular jpg name be saved in my database rest are to be deleted.. Thank you

Comment: This is very confusing? I think you need to be clear on what your questions are, def your final throw away comment re saving to db. Have you given it a go - your code doesn't seem to indicate that you have tried it yourself? I suggest you break your goal down into smaller steps giving you confidence in what is working. You could find yourself going round in circles tweaking js, HTML/CSS and PHP.

Comment: how you are saying that i've not TRIED ??

Comment: If i didn't tried it how i'm saying that its not working !

Comment: My comment re "trying" was related to inserting to db, your ajaximage does not contain any db interaction?

Comment: the code is working inside the inside the html body..what my question is how to echo the code on the body tag.

Comment: oh sorry but that i can do with my self i have given that just for info..also you can see there is `//sqlquery space` in the `ajaximage.php`

Comment: Ok - You may find it easier to just return the image URL from ajaximage and then use JavaScript to place it as a background image.

Comment: your saying that return ".$actual_image_name." to ? sorry but can you please explain me with an example

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34310/discussion-between-user2615947-and-afxdesign)

Comment: ugh ! no one is ready to answer :|

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simplified version of what I believe you are trying to achieve. I have changed your body to a div as body should not be a child of div.

**Javascript + HTML**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ajaxForm').ajaxForm(function(response) { 
        var newImage = response;
        //alert(response); -- check your response is correct
        $('#preview > div').css("background-image","url(" + response + ")");
    });
});
</script>

<div id="preview">
    <div style="background-image: url(testimage1.png); width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>    
</div>
<form method="post" id="ajaxForm" action="ajaximage.php">
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**ajaximage.php**

```
<?php
//Your code returns the url -- omitted your code for simplicity
echo "testimage2.jpg";
```

You should see ajaximage simply returns a url. You can use ajaxForm to grab this response and then use javascript to dynamically update the background image.